# How do I make a div with html layout open in Shadowbox?

Tags: jquery, html, markup, shadowbox

I'd like to open a div with html content in with shadow box.
Does anyone know if this is possible with the plugin as I can't see it anywhere on their site?
http://www.shadowbox-js.com/

Thanks for your help

Judi

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846419/how-can-i-open-inline-div-on-page-load-using-shadowbox, but I don't want the div to open on page load. I'd like it to open when I click an image.

Comment: also found these but can't get them to do what I want still https://github.com/mjijackson/shadowbox/tree/master/examples

Comment: Do you want to open an `image` in the lightbox or `text`?

Comment: I'd like a div with content in it. I'm using a video playlist plugin called - responsive-video-gallery-html5-youtube-vimeo, which I would like to put inside the div. I've used an iframe with shadowbox at the moment but this is bulky as it means multiple html files for playlists instead of just one with all the playlists contained.

Comment: So just think of it as a hidden div with html content in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will get what you need.

An example where the `lightbox` will copy the elements in `#cont` when you click on `a`

```
        <div id="cont" style="display:none">
            <h1>Header</h1>
            <b>Test test</b>
            <i>Test test</i>
        </div>

        <a href="#">Open</a>
```

***And the script***

```
        Shadowbox.init({
            skipSetup: true
        });

        $('a').click(function() {
            var content = $('#cont').html();
            Shadowbox.open({
                content: content,
                player: 'html',
                displayNav:false,
                height: 350,
                width: 350
            });
        });
```

The box may display a black background so you have to change that into another color.

Please note that `shadowbox.js` is a player lightbox designed for playing videos. You may consider using something else for `html` content. **The lightbox must contain a `player` otherwise it won't start.**

Comment: Thanks Spokey, Sorry this doesn't work. Nothing happens when I click

Comment: Also where does rel="shadowbox" go?

Comment: `rel='shadowbox'` is automatically added if you put `skipSetup: false` instead of `true`. Did you put the `script` after the `html`? Or add `onload`

Comment: I made a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/bYwSt/. The `rel` attribute is added to `a`. Read the usage for more http://www.shadowbox-js.com/usage.html